# qmail responds 502 unimplemented on STARTTLS

Tags: php, smtp, email, pear, 502-error

I am trying to send mail with php using the PEAR Mail_queue package. It should be working, and it appeared to work twice, but for some reason I keep getting the following error response from qmail:

```
DEBUG: Recv: 220 domain.com - Welcome to Qmail ESMTP
DEBUG: Send: EHLO localhost

DEBUG: Recv: 250-domain.com - Welcome to Qmail
DEBUG: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
DEBUG: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250-SIZE 20971520
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
DEBUG: Recv: 250 STARTTLS
DEBUG: Send: STARTTLS

DEBUG: Recv: 502 unimplemented (#5.5.1)
```

Any ideas? I am new to getting my hands dirty with SMTP as well as qmail, and this is the first time I've tried using PEAR for anything so I'm having trouble pinpointing where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That QMail instance just doesn't support the STARTTLS extension.
It's a little weird that the extension is advertised in the welcome message, but since QMail needs to be patched in order to support STARTTLS, I guess the patching wasn't done properly.
Bottom line: Nothing your PEAR client can do about it besides not using STARTTLS. Maybe SMTPS on 465/TCP works?

Comment: OK, that makes sense (aside from it still being advertised). I'll try smtps or see if I can use a simpler authentication and see what happens.

Comment: I managed to suppress STARTTLS and it worked. Thank you.